# C#/WPF - Is It possible to create a WebBrowser in a second AppDomain and display it in the first AppDomain?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a WPF application and have been dealing with what seems to be a well documented memory leak in the WebBrowser control.  I have read through many articles to no avail.

I am new to AppDomains.

Is it possible to create a WebBrowser object that lives in a second AppDomain and then add it to a wpf window that exists in my first/original AppDomain?  I am hoping that destroying the second AppDomain when I am done using the WebBrowser control will free up memory that would have otherwise been leaked.

To play around with this I have created a new WPF project (.net 3.5) and have done the following but receive an XamlParseException at the last statement.  I was under the impression the last statement should be giving me a reference to a new WebBrowser control in the second AppDomain.

Any thoughts or guidance is appreciated.

```
    String pathToDll = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v3.5\Profile\Client\PresentationFramework.dll";

    Type t = typeof(WebBrowser);

    AppDomain newAppDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("New domain name");

    WebBrowser webBrowserFromOtherDomain = (WebBrowser)newAppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(pathToDll, t.FullName);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are out of luck, WPF controls don't inherit from MarshalByRefObject, so they cannot cross domain boundaries.

Also, the CreateInstanceAndUnwrap expects an assembly fully qualified name, you can get it from Assembly.FullName (but still it should not work as the object cannot cross domain boundaries).

Comment: After doing more reading it appears that even if this was an element that inherited from MarshalByRefObject, I would only be able to interact with the object through a proxy.  To me this sounds like I wouldn't be able to grab an instance and add it to a container (was thinking of using System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser after initially reading your comment).  Does this sound correct?

Comment: Hmmm, not really sure, I have done cross-domain object uses, and yes, it's done through a proxy, but a transparent one, you get what you think it's your class instance but it really is a proxy. WinForm controls do inherit from MarshalByRefObject, so I assume their proxy will allow to do UI manipulation on different domains.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it out and see what happens.